# List of animations in a View

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to make the following in an ImageButton when clicked:

1- double it's size

2- after step 1, start reducing until it's a dot and at the same time using a fade out effect

3- keep it invisible

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For this use **ScaleAnimation**, It would double the size of ImageButton

```
ScaleAnimation  setSizeForTop = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 2);
```

now,

```
top.startAnimation(setSizeForTop);
```

for reducing the size

```
setSizeForTop = new ScaleAnimation(1, .5f, 1, .5f);
```

for fade out effect we use

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);
```

for invisible

```
 ImageButton.setImageVisibility(gone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ValueAnimator that was introduced in honeycomb (but is also backported in a library called NineOldAndroids).

In your buttons onClick you would load the animation from XML, or create it programmatically, and start it.

You can use an animator set to run multiple animations one after the other.

Heres some (untested) example code:

```
    //set up the scale and fade animation set
    AnimatorSet scaleAndFadeSet = new AnimatorSet();
    scaleAndFadeSet.playTogether( ValueAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, "alpha", 1.0f, 0f), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, "scale", 2.0f, 0f));

    // the top level animation set
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, "scale", 0, 2.0f),scaleAndFadeSet);
    set.setDuration(1000);// 1s animation
    set.start();
```